# cakephp how to do pagination group by datetime but keeping the all the data

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0

So, if I have a usagehistory database table like

```
id     file   email   date_send
1     1.txt   A        2013-01-31 15:26:00  
2     2.txt   A        2013-01-31 15:26:00
3     3.txt   B        2013-01-30 12:26:00
```

and I would like to show it in the view something like

```
Date                   email        File
2013-01-31 15:26:00     A           1.txt
                                    2.txt
2013-01-30 12:26:00     B           3.txt
```

how can I do that, considering pagination in cakephp.
what I've got right now pretty much just show it as is

```
Date                   email        File
2013-01-31 15:26:00     A           1.txt
2013-01-31 15:26:00     A           2.txt
2013-01-30 12:26:00     B           3.txt
```

My code in the controller

```
        $this->paginate =  array(
            'UsageHistory' => array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'UsageHistory.user_id' => $id
                ),
                'order' => 'UsageHistory.date_send DESC'
            )
        );
        $this->set('usageHistory', $this->paginate('UsageHistory'));
```

and in the view

```
<?php if ( !empty($usageHistory) ) { ?>
                            <?php foreach ( $usageHistory as $history ) :?>  
                        <tr>
                            <td class="filename"><?php echo $history['UsageHistory']['file_name']; ?></td>
                            <td class="recip"><?php echo $history['UsageHistory']['recipient_email']; ?></td>
                            <td class="size"><?php echo round($history['UsageHistory']['file_size']/1048576*100)/100 . ' MB'; ?></td>
                            <td class="datesent"><?php echo $this->Time->format('m/d/o h:i A', $history['UsageHistory']['date_send']); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">No Usage History Yet</td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is purely the *presentation* of the data and should therefore be done in the View.

Because you still want all rows to be visible, it's not necessary to modify the query, just the way that the results are shown.

"Dummy" code

```
$curDate = null;

foreach($results as $row) {
   if($row['date'] != $curDate) {
       // new date/time; should be visible
       $visibleDate = $row['date'];

       // Make this the new 'current' date
       $curDate = $row['date'];
   } else {
       // Still the same date; should not be visible
       $visibleDate = '';
   }
   ?>
   <tr><td><?php echo $visibleDate ?></td><td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td><td>...</td></tr>
   <?php
}
```

The same can be done for the 'email' column

Comment: but if I did it like that, that means if I have thousands of data, the page will be based on the number of files instead of the date. because in a sense there should be less page to go through. The main thing about grouping by date is if originally I have 50 pages, than I can only have maybe 20 pages. something like that

Comment: But you're still showing all rows, only separated/grouped by date. Consider the possibility that a single date can contain 1000 rows (files); if your pagesize is '20' records per page you will then effectively show 20 X 1000 = 20000 rows. If you want less pages, present them as I suggested and increase the page size. If you need to jump to a specific date quickly; add a filter-option to your page. The CakePHP pagination also can be passed conditions (e.g. Date between 01-01-2013 and 02-01-2013)